# Showing where complex function is analytic and differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, analyticity

I've been asked to show where the following function is analytic and differentiable;

$$f(z) = x^4 + i(1-y)^4$$ for $z = x + iy$

First, I noted that $u(x,y) = x^4$ and $v(x,y) = (1-y)^4$.

Then, I verified the Cauchy-Riemann equations;
$$u_y = -v_x \implies 0 = 0$$
$$u_x = v_y \implies 4x^3 = 4(y-1)^3 \implies x = y-1$$

Would it then be correct to say that $f$ is analytic where $x = y-1$, but differentiable on all of $\mathbb{C}$??

I'm just a bit confused about what we've been taught in class as to the explicit definitions of an analytic function and a differentiable function, so I guess I'm just asking for some clarification on these terms, using this question as an example.

Any input would be fantastic!!

Comment: What definition of *analytic function* has been given in class ?

Comment: A function is analytic at $z_0$ if it is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.

Comment: Then your function is differentiable on the line $x = y-1$ but nowhere analytic, since a line in $\mathbb{R^2}$ contains no non-empty open subset.

Comment: Also I think you should take the time to note that $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exist and are continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and therefore $u$ and $v$ are differentiable in the real sense everywhere on $\mathbb{R^2}$. Satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations is *necessary* but **not** sufficient for differentiability.